# How to simply check the visibility of cubes?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a camera and a pile of up to 10 cubes. I know the position and orientation of the cubes and the camera. Now I would like to figure out what pixel belongs to what cube and create a labeled image where every pixel belongs to either a cube or nothing. Now I saw [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/85784/how-do-i-check-whether-a-camera-has-unobstructed-view-of-a-gameobject) and the last answer gives a nice list of options. Now the thing is this is just a means to generate a dataset to train a model. The only way I know how I could do that would be to insert the coordinates of my cubes into some game/modeling engine like unity/blender and use existing functions, but this would only be by hand.

What I'm looking for is a small and simple library(c++/python) that let's me insert a few cubes and let's me determine the visibility of the pixels **programmatically**. Right now the only thing I can think of is writing my own ray casting plus polygonisation algorithm, which can't be the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using blender to do what I wanted. I guess it is not the smallest and simplest framework, but it does the job after a (bit ;) ) of [compiling it as a python module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module/117213?noredirect=1#comment205754_117213) and another user helped me [render all cubes with the same color.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117331/how-to-render-objects-with-the-same-color-for-all-sides-of-the-object/117334?noredirect=1#comment205464_117334)